# Hölder inequality problem doubt

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

[image]

How can we get $||\:|f1...f_n|^r\:||_1\leqslant ||\:|f_1|^r\:||_{\frac{p1}{r} }...||\:|f_n|^r\:||_{\frac{pn}{r}}$? The problem 105 only states that $\mathscr{L}_{p1}\supset \mathscr{L}_{p2}\:\:\text{for}\:\:p1\geqslant p2$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking at Problem 5 or 105? In any case, you can use techniques from the proof you posted to prove (ii) from the standard Hölder inequality.